# The functional is continuous

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, proof-verification, continuity

Show that the functional $J(y)=\int_a^b (\sin^3 x+y^2) dx$ is continuous in respect to the $||\cdot||_{\infty}$ norm, at any $y_0 \in C([a,b])$.

Let $y_0 \in C([a,b])$. Then for $y \in C([a,b])$ we have:

$$|J(y)-J(y_0)|=\left| \int_a^b (y^2-y_0^2) dx\right| \leq \int_a^b ||y-y_0||_{\infty} |y+y_0| dx \\ = ||y-y_0||_{\infty} \int_a^b |y+y_0| dx \ \ \ (1)$$

Let $\epsilon>0$.

We are looking to find a $\delta>0$ such that if $||y-y_0||_{\infty}< \delta , y \in C([a,b])$ then $|J(y)-J(y_0)|< \epsilon$.

If $||y-y_0||_{\infty}< \delta$ then $||y||_{\infty}< ||y_0||_{\infty}+ \delta (\star) $

So we can assume that we work for $\delta>0$ such that $\delta<||y_0||_{\infty}$.

For such a $\delta$ we will have that:

if $||y-y_0||_{\infty}< \delta$ then $||y||_{\infty}< 2 ||y_0||_{\infty} (2)$ because of $(\star)$.

$(1)$ because of $(2)$ gives:

$$|J(y)-J(y_0)| \leq ||y-y_0||_{\infty} 3 ||y_0||_{\infty}< \epsilon$$

$$\delta< \min \{||y_0||_{\infty}, \frac{\epsilon}{3 ||y_0||_{\infty}}\}$$

Do we have to take: $$\delta< \min \{||y_0||_{\infty}, \frac{\epsilon}{3 ||y_0||_{\infty}}\}$$

? Couldn't we just consider $\delta=\frac{\epsilon}{3 ||y_0||_{\infty}}\}$?

Also doesn't $(1)$ because of $(2)$ give:

$$|J(y)-J(y_0)| \leq ||y-y_0||_{\infty} 3 ||y_0||_{\infty}(b-a)$$

Or am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

First, note that
$J(y_1)-J(y_2) = \int_a^b (y_1(x)^2 - y_2(x)^2) dx$.

Second, note that $a^2-b^2 = (a+b)(a-b)$.

Hence $|J(y_1)-J(y_2)| \le (b-a) \|y_1-y_2\| \|y_1+y_2\|$.

Now pick $y_0$, and suppose $y \in B(y_0,1)$, then
$|J(y)-J(y_0)| \le 2(b-a) \|y-y_0\| $.

Now let $\epsilon>0$ and pick $\delta = \min(1, {1 \over 2 (b-a)} \epsilon )$,
then if $\|y-y_0\| < \delta$, we have $|J(y)-J(y_0)| < \epsilon$.